# Questions regarding umbrella app ~> Nano/micro services, Communication

Tags: elixir

**-- Background**

I'm working towards replacing some of our endpoint of our currently Rails rest API, with Elixir. I came to fall in love with the idea of an Umbrella, to which contains a HTTP endpoint (A Phoenix app), and a collection of small nano apps; could be a users app that has full responsibility of interactions with the user data.

**--  Questions**

Now i want to be able to scale these services independently, say if there is a larger load on the users service. We are using Docker in our current setup up, so ideally i would deploy more of the users app containers.

This means i need some sort of communication, i currently created a proof of concept using GenServer, which works great, but seems to be wrapped around the idea of passing and changing a state. Whereas i just want to pass some data, or reply :ok if the action succeeded.
I took a look at http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/task-and-gen-tcp.html, ended of confused about what i should use for communicating.
So my first question, what is the most ideal way of communicating between my apps?

I also stumbled upon another pain, while developing i still need my apps to talk together, but this means i need to start each app independently, and pass them a --cookie and a --sname. This is fine for now, as i have just 3 apps, but when i have 10, this is a lot of work. I know i cat start the whole project from the umbrella root, but then, how do i pass the required parameters to the individuel app?

Would deeply appreciate some clearance. Thank you.

Comment: I don't exactly get why "this means I need some sort of communication" holds, but as long as you're sticking inside the Erlang/Elixir ecosystem, http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/distributed-tasks-and-configuration.html is probably more what you want. The parameter passing, well, there are more ways to skin that cat - you can start the distribution system programmatically, for example, instead of having it done for you, see  http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html. I have the feeling your question is a bit too general to warrant an exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erlang and by association Elixir were created with a communications layer built in to the language.  With an umbrella app, you can [build a release](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery) that includes all the applications in a single node initially, and then as scaling needs to happen targeting specific applications in the umbrella, you can build a release for those applications that run as other node(s).

Using the built in methods for internode communications and obeying a few rules will ensure you do not have to change your existing code in order to distribute your nodes to different machines/VMs.

See [this article](http://tjheeta.github.io/2014/12/05/elixir-inter-node-communication) for instructions to experiment with inter-node communications.

Other concepts that are important to understand the overall communications picture in Erlang/Elixir:

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html

http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html

http://erlang.org/doc/man/pg2.html

Keep in mind that just as with TCP or UDP network communications, the first requirement is that the machine(s) must be able to talk over the network and the ports that the Erlang VM is trying to use must be open.

You can use this command line argument when starting an Erlang/Elixir application to limit the range of ports used:

`-kernel inet_dist_listen_min 30000 inet_dist_listen_max 30003`

I believe you need a minimum of 2 or 3 ports open for it to function correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic, just what i was looking for, thank you Jason! :)

Comment: No problem.  I would like to add that the method for communicating between processes in Elixir is the same as between nodes, as you are still just communicating between processes (on different nodes).  That method is `Process.send`.